# Block inline-css from html and use gradient background from external css

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure this is possible, but I have an image stylized from the HTML.
When I got the job, this was like that already.

And now I need to change the style, however, I cannot touch the HTML.
It needs to stay as it is.

I've tried

```
background-image: none;
```

But then, my gradient background from css didn't work as well.

I'll show you my HTML and CSS

Here at codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzQrVe

```css
div.mh-container ul.mh-menu {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: none;
  padding-left: 250px !important;
}

div.mh-container ul.mh-menu:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

div.mh-container ul.mh-menu li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

div.mh-container ul.mh-menu li:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}

li[id^="mh-li-"] {
  min-width: 138px;
}

div.mh-container ul.mh-menu > li {
  background: none;
}

div.mh-container ul.mh-menu > li {
  text-align: center;
}

div.mh-container ul.mh-menu > li > a {
  /* background-image: none !important; */
  font-weight: 600;
}

div.mh-container ul.mh-menu > li a {
  /* display: inline-block;
    color: #aeaeae;
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-position: 3px 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;*/

  color: #161312;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 26px;
  /* Text Shadow */
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #4b433e;

  /* Gradient Background */
  background: #362f2c; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #362f2c 0%, #282321 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0%, #362f2c),
    color-stop(100%, #282321)
  ); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #362f2c 0%,
    #282321 100%
  ); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #362f2c 0%,
    #282321 100%
  ); /* Opera11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #362f2c 0%, #282321 100%); /* IE10+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
      startColorstr='#362f2c',
      endColorstr='#282321',
      GradientType=0
    ); /* IE6-9 */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #362f2c 0%, #282321 100%); /* W3C */

  /* Border Radius */
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;

  /* Box Shadows */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #564b46, 0 1px 1px #181514;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #564b46, 0 1px 1px #181514;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #564b46, 0 1px 1px #181514;

  /* Transition Effect */
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

div.mh-container ul.mh-menu > li a:hover {
  color: #73635e;

  /* Text Shadow */
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;

  /* Gradient Background */
  background: #282321; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #282321 0%,
    #362f2c 99%,
    #362f2c 100%
  ); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0%, #282321),
    color-stop(99%, #362f2c),
    color-stop(100%, #362f2c)
  ); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #282321 0%,
    #362f2c 99%,
    #362f2c 100%
  ); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #282321 0%,
    #362f2c 99%,
    #362f2c 100%
  ); /* Opera11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #282321 0%,
    #362f2c 99%,
    #362f2c 100%
  ); /* IE10+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
      startColorstr='#282321',
      endColorstr='#362f2c',
      GradientType=0
    ); /* IE6-9 */
  background: linear-gradient(
    top,
    #282321 0%,
    #362f2c 99%,
    #362f2c 100%
  ); /* W3C */

  /* Transition Effect */
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
ul.sub div.mh-row li a {
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mh-container" style="">
  <ul id="mh-menu" class="mh-menu">
    <li id="mh-li-mc" class="mh-dc-li">
      <a id="mh-mc" href="#" class="mh-dc" style="background-image: url(https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/004/836/original/dom.png?1500668261); background-position: 2px 50%;">Minha Conta<span class="mh-dc-icon"></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `background-image: none !important`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `!important` to the style attribute for it to override other styles like so:

```
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, blue, red ) !important;
```

Comment: I can't, I sill need to use a background from the css. I want the gradient color to work.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried to fix that, but found no way to do it yet.

Comment: are you saying you want the gradient and the image? as in an overlay?

Comment: No, just the gradient here: div.mh-container ul.mh-menu > li a 

If I use background-image:none; then nothing will appear.